# Nginx try_files URL with query parameter to a PHP file?

Tags: nginx

URL INPUT: https://example.com/t/topic-title/14842?amp=true

OUTPUT Try files:  /htd/index.php with 14842 uri

---

I try But it's not true

```
location ~\?amp=true {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /htd/index.php?uri=$uri;
}
```

Comment: So Where is the question? What is the problem? What is the input and expected output? All I see is a link and some code.

Comment: You can't check query string with `location` or `rewrite` directives, they work with normalized URI which doesn't contain the query part of the request. So this location would never match any request.

Comment: input is: https://howtodiscuss.com/t/topic-title/14842?amp=true   output is: /htd/index.php

Comment: @IvanShatsky and @the grand J, bascially you can see the full question with Nginx code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64129297/detect-url-query-parameter-from-request-in-nginx-config-on-virtual-host

Can anyone please help on this? just need to serve PHP code when person goes to ```?amp=1``` at end of any URL pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {

        # will send to ? amp = 1
        if ($arg_amp) { rewrite ^ /amp/index.php ? q = $uri last; }

        location~\.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass unix: /run/php / php7 .4 - fpm.sock;
        }

    }
```