# Detect URL Query Parameter From Request in Nginx Config On Virtual Host

Tags: php, nginx, redirect, parameters, url-rewriting

I have few virtual hosts (sites) running on this single server.

Right now, on this root virtualhost i have a forum (running on Docker) but served by Nginx `mysite.com` and I have its AMP pages being served on `/amp` route which is
`mysite.com/amp`. These AMP pages are basically 1 single `index.php` file & they all are handled by this 1 file. These are served by PHP using Nginx.

What I want is, when a user hits any of these requests matching below patterns: (like if **ANY URL on this domain** ending with `?amp=1`

```
mysite.com?amp=1

mysite.com/t/my-topic/121?amp=1

mysite.com/c/CategoryCaseInsensitive/13?amp=1

mysite.com/u/john?amp=1

mysite.com/u/john/summary?amp=1
```

THEN

I want to redirect this request and send it to my AMP page (which is running on PHP file and will be then served/handled by `index.php` which is present in `/var/www/amp` ) . Right now the PHP code is being served on `/amp` but i want to serve it on `mysite.com?amp=1` so any URL preceding `?amp=1`

I have tried this code but its not seem to working for all cases:

```
#if ($arg_amp) {
#   return 302 /amp$request_uri;
#}
```

Below is my current NGINX config file for this virtual host:

```
    #Vhost Config Server, serving Ruby on Rails App on Docker on domain root
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate         /var/www/cert/mysite.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /var/www/cert/mysite.key;


    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    location / {
        proxy_ssl_server_name       on;
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:PORT;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_redirect off;

        # Socket.IO Support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_ssl_protocols         TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
       
       #if ($arg_amp) {
       #   return 302 /amp$request_uri;
       #}

    } 
    #Serving PHP code on /AMP route
    location @amp {
           rewrite ^/amp(.*) /amp/index.php?q=$1;
        }
    #will match any prefix for amp, amping, or amp/anything/any  

    location /amp {

    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @amp;
    alias /var/www/amp;

#PHP config for Nginx
     location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }

}
    #/amp route ends
}
```

Is this not possible in Nginx?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be done more simple way. If your `index.php` is the only PHP file needs to be served, you don't need this whole `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` thing.

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        if ($arg_amp) {
            return 302 /amp$request_uri;
        }
        ...
    } 

    location /amp {
        # if you really need an original URI as a query argument
        rewrite ^/amp(.*) /amp/index.php?q=$1 break;

        include fastcgi_params;

        # hardcode script path
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/amp/index.php;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Or you can skip that `rewrite` rule at all, just get an original request URI from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and strip `/amp` prefix from it within your PHP code:

```
    location /amp {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/amp/index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
```

You can even process those requests with your script without 302 redirects:

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        if ($arg_amp) {
            rewrite ^ /amp$request_uri last;
        }
        ...
    } 

    location /amp {
        internal;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/amp/index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

An original URI would be accessible from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.